# Customizing Rails routes to remove model names

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have two models with a has-many/belongs-to relationship. The routes are nested, and I have this in my routes.rb:

```
resources :threads do
  resources :posts
end
```

So I get URLs like example.org/threads/147/posts/372, and example.org/threads/298, etc.

How do I change that so the URLs are more like example.org/147/372, with the models implicit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could configure a route like this:

```
match ':id' => 'threads#show'
match ':thread_id/:id' => 'posts#show'
```

This would work, but it would also cause problems for other routes since it would not only match example.org/123/456, it would also match example.org/user/mark

To make sure it only matches possible id's (numerical) for the models, you can add constraints like this:

```
match ':id' => 'threads#show', :constraints => { :id => /\d*/ }
```